# What is a topic I could easily collect data on that follows a poisson distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

So I have a project for my stat class and we have to form a hypothesis or question that I can do probabilistic modeling on. I really want to do a topic similar to a poisson distribution but I'm a little uncreative with my topics. So what would be something interesting to do?

Comment: The number of traffic accidents that occurs on a particular stretch of road during a month approximately follows a Poisson distribution.

Comment: You could probably find some good examples related to Queueing theory, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory

Comment: The "waiting time" between events in a "Poisson process" follows a Poisson distribution, for example the between phone calls received at an IT help center might be modeled this way (if we pretend everyone works 24 hours a day).